# What is patched by LX 16:32 fixup record

Tags: x86

In LX format description in section
3.13 Fixup Record Table, when describing `SRC = DB Source type field` there is such an option:

`06h = 16:32 Pointer fixup (48-bits).`

**1. How many bytes does this fixup change and how?** I found a particular example of such fixup, it points to 2nd byte of a certain jump instruction:

`66EA665544332211  jmp dword 0x1122:0x33445566`

I assume it at least changes 4-byte offset (33445566), but does it also change 16 bit selector (1122)?

**2. Where can I find more in-depth description of different fixup kinds?** IBM doc seems to assume it to be common knowledge.

Comment: For more information about LX (16-bit Linear Executable) fixup types, see http://www.textfiles.com/programming/FORMATS/lxexe.txt in the section entitled "Fixup Record Table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such fixup both selector and offset parts are patched so that they point to the actual location of the fixup's target.

Comment: I suppose you're right, yet it's unclear where selector comes from, fixup record contains only 'target' field for 32 bit offset part. I should ask another question with concrete fixup data.

Comment: selector comes from wherever the target segment was actually loaded in the memory